# RegisterScript firing order

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know if any of you knows when exactly the scripts injected using ScriptManager's RegisterScript function fired inside a webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found in the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised. The script blocks are not guaranteed to be output in the order they are registered. If the order of the script blocks is important, use a StringBuilder object to gather the scripts together in a single string, and then register them all in a single client script block.

Hope this helps.